# loginRedirect in cakephp not working correctly

Tags: cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.4

In our CakePHP application, we tried Auth component for login.

**This is the AppController:**

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home')
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index','logout','display','home');
    }
```

**This is the UsersController:**

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add');

    }

    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }


    public function index() {
        $this->User->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('users', $this->paginate());
    }


    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->User->create();
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Checkin now'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Then followed these steps:**

1. Entered URL in browser as `http://localhost/cakephp/`
2. From Homepage `home.ctp`, navigated to `http://localhost/cakephp/users/login` for login, using `Login` button
3. Entered username & password and click the Login button
4. then it redirects to the previous visited `home.ctp` page and not the page mentioned in `AppController`.

**Second attempt:**

1. Visited `http://localhost/cakephp/users/login/` directly from URL field
2. then entered login credentials, then it redirects to the correct page as mentioned in `AppController`.

Why Auth component is behaving like this.....

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't that how 'friendly forwarding' works? If you specify a page that redirects, a successful login will get you back there, otherwise you get redirected to the loginRedirect.

Answer (score 0):

check your appcontroller,you are redirecting login from home to dashboard and it cant redirect you from users to login

change your:

app controller

```
        'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'),
```

and usercontroller

```
   public function login() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        /* login and redirect to url set in app controller */

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {

            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'dashboard'));

        }

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in), you'll have to change the redirect as follows:

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            // Prior to 2.3 use `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());`
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the change `return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());`